# Excel Userfom Overwriting Rows

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm still only learning VBA, but I'm having an issue with the below, where data being entered by the userform is overwriting existing rows.

Able to help?

```
' Write data to worksheet
rowcount = Worksheets("Register").Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Register").Range("A4")
    .Offset(rowcount, 0).Value = Me.txtID.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 1).Value = Me.txtRecDate
    .Offset(rowcount, 2).Value = Me.txtPerson.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 3).Value = Me.txtEntity.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 4).Value = Me.cboCorresType.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 5).Value = Me.cboInTray.Value
    .Offset(rowcount, 6).Value = "FALSE"
    .Offset(rowcount, 50).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    .Offset(rowcount, 51).Value = Environ("Username")
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research on the interweb...

```
' Write data to worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Register")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtID.Value
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtRecDate
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtPerson.Value
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtEntity.Value
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Me.cboCorresType.Value
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = Me.cboInTray.Value
ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = "FALSE"
ws.Range("AY" & LastRow).Value = Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss")
ws.Range("AZ" & LastRow).Value = Environ("Username")
```